# SwiftUI LazyHGrid space between dynamic rows

Tags: swiftui, grid

Could you suggest how to have a dynamic number of rows in a grid.
I have 5 words (these could be different width). The idea is to show them next to each other and if there is no enough space -> move to next row

I'm currently using this

```
var rows: [GridItem] = [.init(.adaptive(minimum: 60))]
LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 2)
```

but the space between rows is too big.

Any idea how to make it is smaller?

Thank you

[image: This what I currently have]
[image: This is what I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add spacing in grid item

```
var rows: [GridItem] = [.init(.adaptive(minimum: 60), spacing: 2)]
```